# What's an efficient way to encode a (very long) string from a dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python, encoding, dictionary

I have a dictionary assembled in the format {'character to be encoded':'corresponding binary code', etc.}. I've been encoding like this:

```
def encode(self, text): 
    encoded = ""
    def generator():
        for ch in text:
            yield self.codes[ch]  # Get the encoded representation from the dictionary
    return ''.join(generator())
```

This works fine for short strings, but for novel-length strings it is so slow that it's unusable. What's a faster way to encode a string like this? Or should I completely rethink how I store and manipulate my data?

More code:

I've been testing using `print c.encode(f)`, where f is a string (I just checked this), and c is the encoder object. This works for shorter files - I've tested up to 3000 characters. Thanks to thg435 my encode function is now

```
 def encode(self, text):
        return ''.join(map(self.codes.get,text))
```

`self.codes` is a dictionary of mappings - when the string 'hello' is input it will be set to `{'h': '01', 'e': '00', 'l': '10', 'o': '11'}`. I feel like I should put more code but I've tested the argument ('text') and the dictionary, so I'm not sure what would be relevant as they seem to be the only things that could affect the runtime of this function. The functions that get called before encode work fine in terms of speed - I know this because I have been using print statements to check their output and it is always printed within a couple of seconds of the time of execution.

Comment: why not `return ''.join(self.codes[ch] for ch in text)` ?

Comment: and you can probably use [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.translate#str.translate).

Comment: good ideas, I'll try them both. Oh and there is a typo in that code: the 'c' and 'ch' should be the same.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting the second suggestion to work. Is there a way to use str.translate such that each character can be mapped to a code that is multiple characters long? I've been separating the dictionary into strings using .values() and .keys()

Comment: What about pickle to serialize your objects?

Comment: My version is 2.7.3. Looking up pickle now, looks interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the fastest:

```
''.join(map(codes.get, text))
```

Timings:

```
codes = {chr(n): '[%d]' % n for n in range(255)}


def encode1(text): 
    return ''.join(codes[c] for c in text)

def encode2(text): 
    import re
    return re.sub(r'.', lambda m: codes[m.group()], text)

def encode3(text): 
    return ''.join(map(codes.get, text))


import timeit

a = 'foobarbaz' * 1000

print timeit.timeit(lambda: encode1(a), number=100)
print timeit.timeit(lambda: encode2(a), number=100)
print timeit.timeit(lambda: encode3(a), number=100)


# 0.113456964493
# 0.445501089096
# 0.0811159610748
```

Comment: Thanks. This works really nicely on shorter files, but still causes Idle to stop responding on my 203,000 character long .txt file / string. I'm wondering if there's something else in my code that's slowing it down, although I only call that encode function.

Comment: But also, thanks for taking the time to test that for me! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @FalseAzure: 200K is not that big. Actually, all these methods were able to process that in less than 0.1 second. The problem is definitely somewhere else. You might want to show us more code.

Comment: Ok ignore what was previously in this comment. I'll post more of my code above.

Comment: @FalseAzure: just noticed you're using IDLE. Have you tried your code without it, e.g. in the console?

Comment: Oh thanks, that was significantly faster! Any idea why idle might be so slow?

Comment: @FalseAzure: nope, I don't use IDLE. Might be worth posting a new question.