# Why can IDLE be slower than running a program from the command line?

Tags: command-line, python-idle

I was recently having problems with IDLE stopping responding once it hit a certain point in my code when processing very long strings, as reflected here: [What's an efficient way to encode a (very long) string from a dictionary? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260792/whats-an-efficient-way-to-encode-a-very-long-string-from-a-dictionary-pytho).

That has since been resolved; the same code that caused IDLE to freeze up ran in a second or two from the command line. Now, out of curiosity, why would this be?

(And, yes, I know I should probably use another IDE. However, at the moment I'm only working on a small project and I like how lean and simple IDLE is.)

Answer (score 0):

IDLE chokes when presenting large results. I entered `'x'*100000`, and IDLE took three seconds to display the result. It also froze when I tried to cursor up. The regular Python shell displayed the result practically instantaneously.